# specific css code not working

Tags: html, css

While I was writing a css for a website, I found that some portions of my css did not work as intended. What happened was that within a selector with the highest specificity, when I tried to adjust the width or margins of an element, it did not change. However, within the same selector, other properties could be adjusted without problem.

e.g.:- take this selector

```
.get-touch {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
}
```

This is applied to a button, and I wanted to increase its width.
Even if I change the width to 500px, the width will not change whatsoever. However. any modifications to other properties will be reflected on the browser.

Here, I have attached the file to my particular css file which brings the problem:- https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1CjX_FVqdRjWGRkS3NLOG9tTEE

How can this occur, and what can I do to prevent such problems?

Comment: Can you provide full code?

Comment: @ZhenyaTelegin only the css. is it okay?

Comment: yes. and part where you use get-touch class :)

Comment: `margin` won't apply to inline elements - make sure the button display is `inline-block` or `block`

Comment: @KavindaKeshanRasnayake did you try giving `display:inline-block` to your `button` css. You haven't shared your `HTML` code, we don't know what element you are using on page, is it an `anchor`, `input` or  a `button`. Please share the same, or your question may get closed as it cannot generate basic structure for debugging.

Comment: looking at your description it shows, you are giving all this `CSS` to an `inline` element and thus it's not giving you the desired output. Adding `display:inline-block` should work for.

Comment: Also maybe you want to increase width of parent div with `get-touch` class?

Comment: @DeepakYadav Unfortunately, I am unable to show the html code right now  because I am not sure it can be as of yet.

Comment: But I will check your suggestions.

Comment: @DeepakYadav your suggestion worked. I think adding it as an answer will help me to vote you up. :)

Comment: @KavindaKeshanRasnayake glad to here that. In future, do share such amount of code that your issue can be generated at our side also. Even if you would have added a simple `input/button` or any other tag you are using, you would have got your answer much quickly.

Comment: @DeepakYadav I will keep that in mind.

Comment: You can accept the answer below and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.get-touch {
    display: inline-block; /* Add this */
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
}
```

As you have mentioned that the `button` size is not changing even after giving it `width`, it means you are applying your `CSS` on an `inline` element and thus the browser can't render its `box-model`. 
Adding a `display:inline-block` property will make it work.